# Display User Control in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, user-controls, microsoft-metro, scrollviewer

I have a scroll viewer that I want to display all of my user controls. I have two types of user controls which are education and work. They are just text boxes and a button. I dynamically create various numbers of each and add them to a list of type usercontrol. However I cannot get all of the user controls to display!

Scroll Viewer xaml

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="518" Margin="128,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1123" FontSize="22"/>
```

Code behind

```
List<UserControl> info = new List<UserControl>();
EducationControl educationControl = new EducationControl(school._school, school._degree, school._fieldOfStudy, school._educationStartDate, school._educationEndDate);
info.Add(educationControl);
WorkControl workControl = new WorkControl(work._employer, work._jobTitle, work._jobStartDate, work._jobEndDate);
info.Add(workControl);
myScrollViewer.Content = info;
```

When I set the content of the scrollviewer to info, it just displays a string like:
System.Collections.Generic.list'1[Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl]

However the I can get an individual usercontrol to display properly when I do:

```
myScrollViewer.Content = info.ElementAt(0);
```

How can I display all of the user controls in the scroll viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScrollViewer's content must be a list-style *control*, such as a ListBox. By itself, the ScrollViewer doesn't know how to render a `List<UserControl>`, so it just prints the type name.

It looks like you probably want `items` to become the `ItemsSource` of a `ListBox` or similar control.

Comment: as soon as I posted this I had a hunch it was something like that. Thank you for the quick response, this is what I needed.